How to allow slicer filtering for tasks in David Bacci's PowerBI Gantt Chart
I'm fairly new to PowerBI and have recently gotten into David Bacci's PowerBI Gantt Chart-- was wondering if there was a way to allow filtering such that if a specific task is selected in a slicer, the selected task as well as all its connected (interdependent) tasks will be shown in the Gantt chart while the rest are hidden.
Currently I'm working with two sets of data for my dashboard: One spreadsheet containing all info for Gantt chart and another spreadsheet containing a column with task names I'm using for the slicer. I've created a relationship between the two tables via the columns containing task names in each respective table, but when I try using the slicer, nothing is filtered.
Is there any way to solve this? Thank you!

This is non-trivial but possible. It depends what you mean by dependent - is it the immediate dependent tasks or the full tree of dependent tasks through to the ultimate parent? Either way, you should be able to adapt the solution I created here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78799575/force-directed-graph-in-deneb-vega-for-power-bi/78799679#78799679

Thank you @davidebacci! Regarding your selection measure, I was wondering if it was possible to alter it to account for multiple selections? Currently, when I try to slicer filter for multiple entries, the filtering reverts back to displaying all nodes.
